# Ant creating WAR JAVA

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ant

Good day!

I have been trying to write **ant** file for compilation and making the WAR file for a long time.
But still it doesnt work. At this time I have no build errors, but there is a Tomcat "Resource not found" error, where should be my servlet.

Here is my build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

```
<property environment="env"/>

<property name="dir.src" value="src"/>
<property name="dir.dist" value="ant-dist"/>
<property name="dir.lib" value="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>
<property name="dir.build" value="ant-build"/>
<property name="dir.classes" value="${dir.build}/classes"/>
<property name="tomcat-home" value="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}"/>
<property name="java-home" value="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>

<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${dir.lib}" includes="*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${tomcat-home}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${java-home}" includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${dir.classes}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${dir.dist}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init" >
    <javac destdir="${dir.build}" debug="true" srcdir="${dir.src}" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="war" depends="compile">
    <war destfile="${dir.dist}/SoulVoxServer.war" needxmlfile="false">
        <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
        <lib dir="${dir.lib}"/>
        <classes dir="${dir.classes}"/>
    </war>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${dir.dist}" />
    <delete dir="${dir.build}" />
</target>
```

I thought that the problem can depend on web.xml file missing, but i use annotation so it should work anyway, isn't it?

Thank you!

**EDIT**
I found that my war file doesnt contain any classes. Its structure:

```
+META-INF
--MANIFEST.MF
+WEB-INF
--classes (It is empty)
--lib (here goes my jar files. Its ok)
-Playlist.jsp
```

**EDIT**
I solved that problem and now i see the next:
I have 2 war files:
1) Generated by ant. 13.3 Mb. Doesnt work.
2) Generated by eclipse and has the same files inside (after jar -xvf), but it is only 6.6 Mb size.. Thi one works.

What is that?

Comment: So, what does the war file contain? Where is the servlet code, and what's the URL used to execute it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found that my war file doesnt contain my classes :D Where is my mistake?

Comment: I solved that problem and now i see the next:
I have 2 war files:
1) Generated by ant. 13.3 Mb.
2) Generated by eclipse and has the same files inside (after jar -xvf), but it is only 6.6 Mb size..

What is that?

Comment: Why are you wasting your time and don't use Maven?

Comment: @Michael-O Because Maven is a huge mess unless you totally drink the kool-aid and your whole world revolves around Maven.

Comment: The difference in file sizes is likely to be due to file compression: perhaps ant by default does not compress, whereas Eclipse does? Only you can tell: use `unzip -v` to get some good information about the contents of the files: `jar` is itself a nearly-useless utility.